# Composer update error

Tags: magento2, patches, composer

I'm using Magento2.3 and when I am running composer update command, I got following error message:

> Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch
>   patches/PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch

[image]

It always shows composer trying to remove magento/module-catalog and failed to apply patches.